# Storyboard issue with Xcode 6 and 7

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard

Why my Main Storyboard appears like shown at Above? I made a copy of the project but now both of them have the same problem with the storyboard! I can run the app using the simulator and it works fine, but I can't see any labels or the buttons.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/35AHlq7]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your device layout....
Actually it makes on other layout like `wAny hAny` and now you show it on other layouts like `wCompact hRegular`....thats why the problem occurs...

Here is the visual site of it....

[image]

> To prevent this type of things...you need to give constraints to your objects..after making correct constraints, the size classes won't matter that much except adaptive layout

Answer (score 0):

Its because of Auto Layout Stuff. Set proper auto layout to you label object.

For eg.

Set `Leading,Trailing,Top & Bottom` layout to your label & then run your application. You will be able to see it on your screen.