# Can't see elements from storyboard inside viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, storyboard, viewcontroller

some elements from my storyboard don't appear since I change the viewcontroller size to 4.7inch. But if I create another viewcontroller and I put some object inside, they are appearing. What's wrong with these viewcontrollers?

[image]

Comment: You probably forgot to add constraints to your subviews

Comment: Are they simply disappearing when you change the size from auto to fixed or only when you run on devices with different sizes?

Comment: On my friend computer, elements are well displayed inside the viewcontrollers, with the same project. They are disappearing just from my storyboard, in my simulator they are ok.

Comment: check this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734206/storyboard-issue-with-xcode-6-and-7/30780770#30780770

Comment: try disabling and then enabling the size classes . Worked for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the UI elements or constraints you have added to the view controller with specific size class will become inactive while to change to some other size class. for example the UI elements or constraints added to view controller with compact width | Any height will become inactive while you change to Any width | Any height.

You can enable it by checking the option in your attribute inspector[scroll down to the bottom]. Please refer to the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Wow ... Easy to understand with screenshot. :) great work Pavithra :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display all your objects in different size classes, you should use auto layout....it manage your object to display in different size classes...

So, The solution to prevent your object to hidden from different size classes, use autolayout

Here is the image...that explains better than words

[image]

In this image I gave autolayout to button using `wAnyhAny`...for best practice..